# неправильные символы при парсинге

Tags: python, json, requests, bs4

написал небольшой парсер ссылок с сайта с сериалами. Сам парсер работает отлично, но вот при сохранении спарсенных файлов в формате json в самом файле появляются символы отступов \n. Из-за этого чтение информации довольно затруднено и у меня не получается
это исправить. Вот сам код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json

headers = {
    'accept': '*/*',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.143 YaBrowser/22.5.0.1816 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'
}

figure = 0
tureckie_film = {}
while figure <= 20:
    url = 'https://lordserial.live/tureckie/' + 'page/' + str(figure) + '/'
    print(url)
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')

    film_href = soup.find_all('a', class_='th-in with-mask')

    for item in film_href:
        item_text = item.text
        item_href = item.get('href')

        tureckie_film[item.text] = item_href

    figure += 1


with open('tureckie_film.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    json.dump(tureckie_film, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
item.text.strip().replace('\n', ' ')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]